# menu-mobile does not open after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have a code with a mobie-menu that when the icon is clicked, it opens and closes.

I also added 'scroll' functionality when the page scrolls down to hide the scroll.

But everything seems to work, when I enter the first time it opens and closes normally, but when I scroll and try to click on the menu again it does not open anymore.

I can't find the error in the console, could someone help me?

```js
//barra de rolagem
let nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
let scrollAnterior = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let scrollAtual = window.pageYOffset;
  let alturaTotal = document.body.offsetHeight;

  if (scrollAtual > scrollAnterior) {
    nav.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    nav.style.display = 'block';
  }

  if (scrollAtual == alturaTotal) {
    nav.style.display = 'block';
  }
  scrollAnterior = scrollAtual;
});


//adicionar menu hamburgue
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('menu-visible');
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  // Verifica se o menu está aberto e se o botão de toggle foi clicado
  if (menu.classList.contains('menu-visible') && menuToggle.clicked) {
    // Fecha o menu
    menu.classList.remove('menu-visible');
  }
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .menu-visible {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a href="/index.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-book-bible"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="menu-item appear">
      <ul class="menu fade">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        <li id="logo" class="logo logo-item">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="./img/icons8-igreja-40.png" alt="Descrição da imagem" title="Descrição da imagem">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="./login-cadastro/login.html">Login /Cadastro</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: When I create [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvkw3z8f/) from your code, there's only a blank page. I'm guessing it should not look like this. Have you posted the relevant bits of code, from which we could try and reproduce the issue? Please, try and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your menu-visible class should have a position of fixed. so that it will appear where ever the screen is.Right now it is probably appearing at the top of the page when you click on it and since you're scrolling to the bottom you can't see it.